# git merge: fatal: I cannot read more than 8 trees

Tags: git, merge

Tried to merge `branch-1000` into `dev` that throws the following error.

```
$ git checkout dev

$ git merge branch-1000
Trying simple merge with branch-1000
Simple merge did not work, trying automatic merge.
Auto-merging file_a.py
Auto-merging file_b.html
Trying simple merge with dev
fatal: I cannot read more than 8 trees
Merge with strategy octopus failed.
```

It's fixed through a couple of `git reset --soft HEAD~1` and `commit` the outstanding changes. It's perfect to merge.

What is the issue?

Comment: Alternative viewpoint: in ten years of using `git`, I haven't had any use for `git merge`.

Comment: @Kaz: Alternative viewpoint: you were doing it wrong for ten years of using git :):):):)

Answer (score 1):

`git merge branch-1000 dev` does not merge `branch-1000` with `dev`.

The *target* of `git merge`—the place the new merge commit will go—is *always* your *current* branch.  If you want to merge `branch-1000` into `dev`, use:

```
git checkout dev
git merge branch-1000
```

If you want to merge `dev` into `branch-1000`, use:

```
git checkout branch-1000
git merge dev
```

What you did was run an *octopus merge* (which failed, but which left your index in a semi-merged state—it merged the tip commit of `branch-1000` into your current commit).  You then used `git reset --soft HEAD~1`, which cleared out the in-progress merge state *and* backed one commit *out* of your current branch—probably not a good idea—but left your index unchanged; and then `git commit`, which made an ordinary non-merge commit with what was in your index.  All of this happened on your *current* branch: whichever one `git status` says you're "on", when `git status` says "on branch _____" (fill in the blank).

Comment: The active branch was `dev`

Comment: Ah, in that case you invoked an unnecessary octopus merge, which should have succeeded given that the first step succeeded.  It's not clear why it failed.

Comment: No, I have been doing merging in such a way for year. It's the first time to have such a case.

Comment: @caot: Whatever. If your active branch was `dev` then the merge command should be `git merge branch-1000` not `git merge branch-1000 dev`. You were doing it wrong for a year and apparently you were just lucky. Really.